# DATA NOT INSERT, cause of near table syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

After i click on "AddData" button, then the app show "DATA NOT INSERT".
How to fix this problem?

Who knows where to get a good tutorial for learning SQLite?

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "table": syntax error
     E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting NAME=hi MARKS=98 SURNAME=ju
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO student.table(NAME,MARKS,SURNAME) VALUES (?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
    at com.example.user.sqliteapp2.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:42)
    at com.example.user.sqliteapp2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    V/RenderScript: 0x7f27c755c000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
    E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f27cf39e610
```

This is my code.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME ="student.table";
public static final String COL_1="ID";
public static final String COL_2="NAME";
public static final String COL_3="SURNAME";
public static final String COL_4="MARKS";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS TEXT);");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String name,String surname,String marks){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `public static final String TABLE_NAME ="student.table";` I'd call the table simply `Students`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this line to create the table :-

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COL_1+ " INTEGER," + COL_2 + " TEXT," + COL_3+ " TEXT," + COL_4 + " TEXT" + ")";);
```

and please be careful to write the code. because wrong syntax does produce the error. so please write the code same as it is i wrote.

Comment: if you have any problem then you can ask me.

Comment: it say" no such table : Students " . i replace my TABLE_NAME="student.table" to TABLE_NAME="Students"

Comment: THANK ALOT FOR YOUR HELP^^

Comment: @JunJie  please vote me up. and accept my answer .if your problem has been solved.

Comment: 'E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Students
        E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting NAME=yr MARKS=65 SURNAME=ru
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Students (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Students(NAME,MARKS,SURNAME) VALUES (?,?,?)'  *It show this error. but i can't find the wrong.*

Comment: change the database version :-                                                                            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

to

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; and in your constructor :-public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,2);

}

Comment: but i can't find the "public static final int databse_version = 1" .where it locate.